# ListView can't handle TranslateAnimation well

Tags: android, listview, animation

If I add a `TranslateAnimation` to the `listview`,for example,let listview move up and keep its performance in the end,the listview will be animated successfully.But the problem is that the item of listview can't handler the touch event correctly.

When I touch on item1,the item2 will be selected and launch `item2's onClick()` method.Something just like that the view has moved but the touch event still relate to the view's last position.

I showed my code as follow :

```
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,dd));

    Animation animation=new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,-height*3);
    animation.setDuration(500);
    animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, position+"", 0).show();
        }
    });
```

When I use `View.animate().translateY()` to animate the listview ,the item can handle the touch event correctly.The only shorcoming is that this method is supported in **API 11** or higher,while I use  **API 8**.

If someone has more wise solution,please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer.If you use Animation to move View,the View's position actually don't move.It just updates the canvas's matrix.So it causes that what you see is not actually what it is. If you want to touch the view,you'll find you are touching the wrong position.